# Show that $m = \pm 2$ or $m = \pm 3.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $$R = \left\{\frac{a + b\sqrt{-19}}{2}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv b \mod 2 \right\} = \mathbb{Z} \left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2} \right] = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha].$$

and define $d:R \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ to be a function satisfying: $a,b \in R$ with $a \ne 0$, and there exists $q,r \in R$ such that $b = aq + r$ with $r = 0$ or $d(r) < d(a).$

> Let $m \in R$ be an element with $d(m)$ minimal, subject to the condition that $m \ne 0$ and $m$ is $\textbf{not a unit}.$ By definition of euclidean domain, there exist $q,r \in R$ such that $$2 = mq + r, \hspace{1mm} r = 0 \text{ or } d(r) < d(m).$$
>
> Conclude from these conditions on $r$ and the definition of $m$ that $r = 0$ or $r = \pm 1$. By exploring these cases, show that $m = \pm 2$ or $m = \pm 3.$

I can see how $r = -1$ or $r = 0$ but not $r = 1.$ If $r = 1,$ then $2 = mq + 1 \Longleftrightarrow 1 = mq.$ Wouldn't this mean that $m$ $\textbf{is a unit}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in noting that the case $r= 1$ is impossible because $m$ was assumed to not be a unit.  The point is that the condition $r= 0$ or $d(r) < d(m)$ restrict $r$ to be $0$, $1$, or $-1$, and only two of these cases are possible by our assumption on $m$.